# How do I create a deployment user on AWS that is truly least privilege?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, deployment, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

We want to have deployment users to use in our pipelines, purely for programmatic access. These users will be created per project, rather than using one deployment user for all stacks.

I'm trying to lock down the resources that these deployment users have permission to change, but I'm struggling due to the fact that the ARN is not yet known until the stack is created, meaning that creating the IAM policy to restrict it to only certain resources is proving difficult.

For example, say I want to create an application load balancer (with listeners, rules etc) - I want the deployment user to have permission to create an ALB (easy enough) but I want the deployment user to only have permission to delete or modify the newly created ALB, not any other ALBs.

Any tips / smart ways to do this? The ARNs are generated and "random" as I dislike naming my resources and having to modify the names if I change a setting that requires replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IAM policy conditions to restrict access to resources based on tags.

For example, you can add two policy statements with a condition element to allow specific actions on a resource:

- User1 can create a resource only if the request contains `owner=user1` tag.
- User1 can update or delete a resource only if `owner=${aws:username}` tag is attached to the resource.

You can find policy example in this guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_tags.html

Comment: Sounds like it could work, however does it work if you're creating the resources and applying the tags with that user?

I'll test it out and update, thanks for the tip.